# How to reorder an Array

Tags: c#

I want to change the first and last index of every array, so the output in this scenario would be: [2,3,1], [9,4,6] [5,8,4].

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[][] array1 =
  {
       new []{1,3,2},
       new []{6,4,9},
       new []{4,8,5}
   };
    foreach (int i in Snail(array1))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}


public static int[] Snail(int[][] array)
{
    List<int> snail = new List<int>();
    foreach (int[] list in array)
    {
        foreach (int i in list)
        {
          // how do I change place with first and last index
        }
    }
```

Comment: Store index 1 in a temp variable, replace index 1 with index 3 and then set index 3 to the temp variable.

Comment: You don't need to loop over content of lists, because you don't do any repetitive action within list. You only need to modify 2 elements out of all

Comment: check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49494535/moving-the-first-array-element-to-end-in-c-sharp

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I swap two values of an array in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43759043/how-can-i-swap-two-values-of-an-array-in-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need one loop since you know the exact two indices you want to operate on

```cs
foreach (int[] list in array)
{
    if (list.Length < 2) continue; //need 2 elements to swap

    int temp = list[0]; //head is stored temporarily
    list[0] = list[^1]; //swap happens
    list[^1] = temp; //now set tail as temp value (the original head)
}
```

Note that `list[^1]` is the same as saying `list[list.Length - 1]`, both meaning the last element of the array

Comment: Instead of using a temporary variable, you can also write use a tuple assignment like this: `(list[0], list[^1]) = (list[^1], list[0]);`.

Comment: @FstTesla I haven't worked with Tuples much but this is interesting, could you elucidate a bit as to what is going on here?

Comment: This is leveraging the multi-assignment construct `(a1, ..., an) = someExpr;` where `someExpr` can be deconstructed as a n-tuple (a pair in this context). This also includes the special case `(a, b) = (b, a);`, which is desugared as the good old swap with a temporary variable.